# How can I use Multile RewriteRules in Apache for one RewriteCond?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, user-agent

I am trying to check if the user agent is facebook or not. I was added this code in Apache conf:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9][L]
  RewriteRule .? - [E=customerAgent:facebook][N]

  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com:4201/$1 [L]
```

Now, what I exactly need is to check if the user agent is facebook or not. 
So, I was tried to add an env variable which called "customerAgent" then redirect to the same URL with deferment port number, by this result I have 2 rewrite rules but it did not work. What is the problem? and how I can add an env var then redirect to the same URL with port? since I need this env var in the code to know if it is a facebook or not.
If its not possible, is there another way to add parameter (e.g. get parameter) rather than env var?

Comment: **1** when you have more than one flag for a `RewriteRule` you have to separate them with `,` inside the same `[ ]`.  **2** No you cannot have one `RewriteCond` apply to many `RewriteRule`.  You can have many `RewriteCond` before a single `RewriteRule`, but not the reverse.    **3** similar to 1, in your `RewriteCond` you must put a space before `[L]`  **4** why verify the user agent starting it with `(` ?

Comment: Can you provide me withe the correct RewriteRule query to my case?

Comment: I tried this code

 ` RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9])
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com:4201/$1 [E=customeUserAgent:facebook,L] `

But it did not worked! what should I do? @nic3500